# OpenLayers 6 add rulers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, react

I'm trying to add vertical and horizontal rulers on top of my map. In OpenLayers 2 I have seen code that had VerticalRuler and HorizontalRuler as attributes but I can't find something similar in version 6. Has it been removed as a feature or has it been renamed?

An image that showcases how it should look:

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of those rulers? Shall they display the scale or coordinates of the map extent?

Comment: They will display the coordinates on the map. Imagine the upper left corner will start at 0 and increments by 1 till the other end of the map.

Comment: The ol-ext graticule http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/canvas/map.control.graticule.html allows you to display only its border, and you can set the projection to match your view projection.  If that isn't sufficient for the needs looking at the source code might help you develop your own.